# How to remove background image from a transparent button

Tags: html, css

I have a background image which is a green thick line and on top of it I a have heading and a transparent button with an icon. I want the background image not to be visible in the heading and the button.
This is what I am having now,
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DXOL.png)

This is what I want to achieve, [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuLWQ.png)

I can easily do this if the button does not have transparent color effects, Is there a way to do this while maintaining transparency effects?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <h2 class="headerclass">Sample Text</h2>
  <div class="text-right icon-box icons">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="iconHelp"></i>
        <span>ABC</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item"><span>Some dropdown item</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.icons {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url(/design/greenline.svg);
}
.btn-default:hover {
    background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.65);
    background-clip: content-box;
}
.icon-box {
    padding-top: 7px;
    height: 31px;
}
.iconHelp {
    content: url(/design/help.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block;
}
.headerclass {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: inherit;
}
.btn-default {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    height: 46px;
    width: 96px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-radius: 22.9px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

I have tried using `overflow:hidden` in the `.icon-box`, but then the dropdown menu get hidden as well.I also tried setting z-index but no luck.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

For the < h2 >, try to just add "background-color: white;"

I can't see where the grey color in the button appears, is it an rgba or is that color from the svg? If it's from the svg, enter the svg file and set a solid grey background color instead, it looks like it's just slightly transparent.

(I couldn't test the code properly but this might be worth a try)

Comment: It appears at button hover. see .btn-defaul:hover class

Comment: Thanks for you answer, changing the background-color of h2 will work, but what if the page has different background colors, then I will have to change h2 background color for each page. Is there a way i can bring h2 and the button to upper layer and keep the green line behind?

Comment: Ah okay. So wouldn't the solution simply be removing the alpha and slightly changing the hue of the button?
And for the second one; I don't think so. Because the h2 is only text, and in order to cover the line in the background you would need a background color on it. There might be a snazzy workaround, but I don't know of any, unfortunately